# How can I create Shuffle play (with GUI) in java

Tags: java, user-interface, shuffle, jlist, audio-player

I have to create an application for audio stream with different functionalities. I am stuck with the shuffle play action. Because on my previous project were GUI wasnt included I created this method where I created a new playlist with a different order.

But now where I have the GUI part and I need to show the playlist in a JList I cant change the original playlist. How am I supposed to get random songs when I press Next without changing the original playlist? Thank you.

```
public ArrayList<String> playRandom(ArrayList<String> songsPath, Player p) {
        ArrayList<String> newPlaylist = new ArrayList<>();
        
        while(songsPath.size()>0) {
            String song = songsPath.get(randomIndex(songsPath.size()));
                songsPath.remove(song);
                    newPlaylist.add(song);
        }
        return newPlaylist;
        
    }
```

That's what I used to do but it changes the original playlist which is a problem if someone wants to go back to playing the songs in the original row.

Comment: Logically, why not copy items of playlist before apply random operation to other public list like "oldPlaylist" so you can go back

Comment: @elgsylvain85 but then I change the view of the jlist right?

Comment: @elgsylvain85 the problem if i unselect the random button i want to be the same like nothing has changed and if i select random the order will be random but the list wont change

Comment: Hint: look at `Collections.shuffle()`